# Using Newton's Generalized Binomial Theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am trying to use Newton's Theorem in a proof with some inequalities. I have something of the form $(a+b)^c$ in my denominator, where $0<c<1$, and I'd like to find a **sharp** expression less than or equal to this with at least 2 terms (exactly 2 would be nice). Since it is not true in general that $(a+b)^c \ge a^c+b^c,$ my first idea was to try and use Netwon's Binomial Theorem to see if I can find an expression involving a,b,c which is less than $(a+b)^c$.

I am fiddling with an example to see if I understand:

Since $r\choose{k}$$=0$ when $r<k$,

$(5+2)^.5 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty $$.5\choose{k}$$5^{.5-k}2^k=5^.5,$ which is clearly wrong.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the statement "${r\choose k}=0$ for $r<k$" is true only for integers $r,k$.

Answer (score 3):

We don't have $\binom rk=0$ if $k>r$ for the generalized binomial coeffiecient if $r$ is not integer. 
$$\binom rk=\frac{r\cdot(r-1)\cdot ...\cdot (r-k+1)}{k!}\,.$$